# Attaching <a href></a> in GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: php, mysql, href, concatenation, group-concat

I want to attach  string to GROUP_CONCAT function using CONCAT().
I tried the following :

```
$str1 = "<a href='show_bug.cgi?id ='>";
$str2 = "</a>";
$query = "select count(cbm.bug_id) as count,(select concat(round((count(cbm.bug_id)/(select count(*) from techzilla.category_bug_map cbm,techzilla.bugs b where b.assigned_to =$userId  and cbm.bug_id=b.bug_id) * 100 ),2),'%')) as Percentage ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('$str1', bug_id,'$str2') separator ',') as BugIds from techzilla.bugs b left join techzilla.category_bug_map cbm on cbm.bug_id = b.bug_id where b.assigned_to = $userId and b.creation_ts >= '$fromDate 00:00:00' and b.creation_ts <= '$toDate 00:00:00' and cbm.os IN ('$opess')";
```

But when i printed the query, i got the following error :

```
select count(cbm.bug_id) as count,(select concat(round((count(cbm.bug_id)/(select count(*) from techzilla.category_bug_map cbm,techzilla.bugs b where b.assigned_to =1078 and cbm.bug_id=b.bug_id) * 100 ),2),'%')) as Percentage ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('', bug_id,'') separator ',') as BugIds from techzilla.bugs b left join techzilla.category_bug_map cbm on cbm.bug_id = b.bug_id where b.assigned_to = 1078 and b.creation_ts >= '2013-05-01 00:00:00' and b.creation_ts <= '2013-06-06 00:00:00' and cbm.os IN ('Windows')
Bad query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show_bug.cgi?id ='>', bug_id,'') separator ',') as BugIds from techzilla.bug' at line 1
```

can anyone please help in fixing this??

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because of the quote in your `$str1`, i would suggest to escape them

```
$str1 = "<a href=\'show_bug.cgi?id =\'>";
```

This should prevent query to split string and `>` as your error is pointing

Comment: i escaped the quotes like this.But still getting the same error :(

Comment: @Jen try to remove those quote too and concatenate it (".$str1.", bug_id, ".$str2.")

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(".$str1.", bug_id,".$str2.") separator ',') 

tried like that. still the same error .

Comment: would you please `echo $query;` before executing and post here what it prints?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31321/discussion-between-fabio-and-jenifer-justin)

Answer (score 0):

I took the part of the query where you are using $str1 and $str2 and tried in my local machine and instead of using variables i directly passed href in query like below

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(\"&lt; a href=show_bug.cgi?id=&gt;\",id,\"&lt;/a&gt;\") separator ',') as BugIds 
from table_name
```

It's working here. Hope it works for you.